# React Native IOS - app gets stuck

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode8

I don't know whats going with my project but every time i try to run this .xworkspace file, it gets stuck at the default splash screen of react native. Please refer to the error below[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

You might have to check your xcode console and enable debug mode for more information.